# Basic object instantiation from a Java point of view to Python

Tags: java, python, oop, porting

I am trying to learn Python by porting an old Java project I did some time ago to Python.

But I will present here my doubt in a more simplified way...

I want to make my code as Object Oriented as possible...

This is the basic doubt that I got...

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnotherClass another = new AnotherClass(); // I instantiated an object
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

When I instantiate this object, I can work on procedural code in AnotherClass() and get the output from there...

```
public class AnotherClass {
   public AnotherClass(){
    System.out.println("Output from AnotherClass()");
   }
}
```

and I get this:

```
Output from AnotherClass()
```

How can I do the same thing but in Python... (this is my first time trying to understand OOP but in Python!)

I hope an answer to my question will help another programmer that wants to learn a new language through porting!

EDIT: I am currently using python 2.7....
Sorry for not declaring the version...

Comment: Do you just want the `print()` function (or `print` statement in Python 2.x versions) to output a string?

Comment: You should read the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 :)

Comment: Then the tutorial is https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to translate AnotherClass to python

```
class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Output from AnotherClass()")
        self._x = 0


another_class = AnotherClass()  # get instance of AnotherClass
```

There's no `new` in python. I assume You already know `this` keyword in Java, `self` in python do the same thing, you can access instance variables like `self._x` but `self` is not a reserved keyword